# Proper SE site to ask about low rate of coronavirus at India vs China

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have seen the low rate of detected coronavirus at India vs China until now ( 28 Feb 2020) shown based of [this site](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/)'s stochastic data, like this:

[image]

So, where can ask about the medical situation in India, and if these data about are India correct, or is the system ignoring some real infections, or don't they have access to counting them with an official system?

Comment: Questions about current situations don't do well on most SE sites, since the information in the answers may no longer be accurate a day later. If you're looking for numbers of people gotten ill in a specific area, local or national news sites would be your best bet. Not the SE network.

Comment: It's a good question, not only for India but in general. Basically you ask yourself, how many unreported cases there are and if the fraction of unreported cases differs from country to country. The problem with unreported cases is probably that nobody knows much about them. It's a very practical statistical question. There cannot be a definitive answer. Maybe ask some practitioners of the mathematics of epidemiology. In London there is a whole university department about it (https://www.lshtm.ac.uk/research/faculties/eph/ide), but they might be very busy right now.

Comment: If I am reading the Worldometer site correctly, then the situation seems to have reversed: China’s count is now suspiciously low compared to India’s. I guess this shows the problem with asking about current situations.

Answer (score 10):

You might have some luck on [Medical Sciences](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/) (formerly Health Stack Exchange). It has [a few questions about public health](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-health) and the most recent one is about the corona virus. Please check their [help center](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before asking a question, to make sure it's up to their quality standards.

Comment: Usually questions that invite speculation are not well-received there, nor are questions about current events where it is not possible to provide a sufficiently referenced answer.

Answer (score 4):

Asking whether a published factoid is true, and/or what the current evidence says, might be on-topic on Skeptics.SE.

Asking why (and not just whether) it's so would not be on-topic there, unless you could find a published claim which purported to explain why (in which case you could ask whether that claim too is true).

They too have [a FAQ](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/faq-welcome-to-new-users) -- and some reluctance to answer questions about [current events](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2870/2703), I don't know how that would rule in this case.

Comment: I am not sure what the actual question is here, and it is definitely not clear that there is a [*notable* claim](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1491/how-should-we-enforce-notability) being questioned here.